# How to put different label for each points in a scatterChart built using ng2-chart

Tags: angular

```
<canvas baseChart
  [datasets]="scatterChartData"
  [options]="scatterChartOptions"
  [colors]="chartScatterColors"
  [legend]="bubbleChartLegend"
  [chartType]="scatterChartType">
</canvas>
```

How can I add unique label to each points.

Comment: I Got the solution.

Comment: Look at https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/1176#issuecomment-773391454